# What is the physical meaning of the definite integral of the superficial current density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current

Studying the experiment of a magnet falling down through a copper tube, the problem gives me the graph of the surface current density, as a function of $x$, $x$ varying on the longitudinal axis of the tube (the center of the graph corresponds to the center of the magnet).
The function is:
$$
y=  \frac{3x}{x^2+4}
$$
It asks me to calculate the area under the graph between two of the inflection points, but the problem is when it asks me if this area has a physical meaning and, if so, to explain it, but I could not figure it out, does anyone have any tip about this?
The only thing that came up to my mind is that that value can be used to calculate the current of the tube  between the two inflection points, by multiplying it by $2 \pi r$, where $r$ is the radius of the tube, but in this case, shall I use the internal radius of the tube or the external one, or the mean value?
Thanks in advance.